# Use Swift Framework in an Application

Tags: xcode

Xcode 6

1) created a Workspace

2) Created a Cocoa Touch Framework, selecting
    Swift as the language.

3) Created an Application

4) Added Framework in "Build Phases"

I get "Use of unresolved identifier 'ClassName'"